# What Resident Evil games are in the main series

Tags: resident-evil-series

I just completed the 4th resident evil game. Now I am on a bit of a Resident Evil hype and want to play more games. Something that bothered me was not understanding all the relations that characters had with each other. Therefor I am looking to play more of them. I have however trouble identifying which games belong to the "Main series".

To further clarify. I mean games that directly tie into events regarding the Resident Evil Universe. So a spin-off game that really isn't a fully fledged standalone game but more a quick add-on does not qualify (unless it has actual canon to the main series). I am also looking for those that can be played on the PC. (yes Remasters are fine as long as they are on PC).

I know game identification is not allowed but I feel like this falls outside that spectrum. If people disagree I will remove the question .

Comment: Hard to say.  I want to say 0-7, Code: Veronica, and both Revelations games.  However, I can't say that for sure.

Comment: if the question is bad in a way say so. That way i can improve it. Simply down voting it won't improve its quality.

Comment: AFAIK, all the console-level games are in the same continuity.  Yes, it gets pretty twisty in there.  There were a couple of old-school mobile games that were definitely not the same continuity (I'm talking pre-iPhone shitty cell phone games) and I'm unsure about the MMO as I never played it.

Comment: Thanks, for the clearup. If you can make an answer out of it I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resident evil series, order by **story line**, not release date Also with roles:

- Resident Evil Zero *(main series)*

> Rebecca Chambers (S.T.A.R.S Member)

- Resident Evil 1 - or remake *(main series)* *Also Umbrella Chronicles (spin-off)*

> Jill Valentine, Chris Redfield (S.T.A.R.S Member)

- Resident Evil 2 *(main series)*

> Leon S. Kennedy (S.T.A.R.S Member), Clair Redfield (Chris's sister)

- Resident Evil Outbreak *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil 3 *(main series)*

> Jill Valentine

- Resident Evil Outbreak File 2 *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil Survivor *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil CODE:Veronica *(main series)*

> Claire Redfield

- Resident Evil Survivor 2 *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil The Darkside Chronicles *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil Dead Aim *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil 4 *(main series)*

> Leon S. Kennedy

- Resident Evil Revelations *(main series)*

> Jill Valentine

- Resident Evil 5 *(main series)*

> Chris Redfield

- Resident Evil Revelations 2 *(main series)*

> Claire Redfield

- Resident Evil Umbrella Corps *(spin-off)*
- Resident Evil 6 *(main series)*

> Chris/Leon

- Resident Evil 7 *(main series)*

> Chris Redfield (Just in "not a hero" DLC)

- Resident Evil 8 Village *(main series)*

> Chris Redfield  (playable)

Answer (score 0):

Which resident evil games are in the main series?

Resident Evil 0

Resident Evil 1 and it’s remake.

Resident Evil 2 and it’s remake.

Resident Evil 3 and it’s remake.

Resident Evil: Code Veronica.

Resident Evil 4 plus Separate Ways.

Resident Evil Revelations.

Resident Evil 5 plus Lost in Nightmares and Desperate Escape.

Resident Evil Revelations 2 plus The Struggle and Little Miss.

Resident Evil 6.

Resident Evil 7 plus Not a Hero and End of Zoe.

Resident Evil Village.

Oh yeah, quick edit. I must also mention the daughters DLC for RE7. It’s a prequel dlc to the main game.

And yes, I mentioned all the dlc’s here because they are essentially extensions to the main games themselves. I recommend playing them.

Comment: Can you clarify how this answer deviates from the accepted one and why the differences are important?

Comment: @Joachim it looks like this answer includes village, although the other answer may be better served by being edited